# Form validation and submission (java test case)

Tags: java, http, jsf, jsf-2

I'm struggling with a small problem. Here is my setup:

- simple JSF 2.x xhtml page, with simple form

  - managed bean for login name and password
  - managed bean tied to "action" of submit button
  - custom validator
- java test case

I want to trigger( from test case ) form submission, in order to trigger validator and managed been method tied to "action" attribute of submit button.

Is this even possible? Ive googled a bit and tried few things, but still fail to trigger validation.

Possibly Im failing to address POST request properly or to setup something in deployed web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible very well.

- Deploy application
- Use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and try to click on the button after setting wrong data
- Read the response (using Selenium) and parse the error message in expected `DIV`

**See**

- [Selenium Click Command](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/the-selenium-click-command/)